# How do you change the 'efficiency' of a mirror-like reflection on glass?

Tags: mirror, reflection, roughness

I'm looking to create the glass top on a coffee table. My reference in real life is basically a piece of glass. I can see through it easily but not perfectly, so my Transmission is set to .87 to make up for light loss through the glass. The glass is also reflective, so the Roughness is set to 0 for the most part. However, this causes my Blender glass to become mirrorlike. While the reflections should be 'mirror' accurate, they should also be much darker. What setting on the principled BSDF would I use to effect this sort of stat?